# Force project to be recompiled using dotnet build

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

Using `dotnet build` the project will not by recomplied if there are no changes:

```
Project {project name} was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
```

Is it possible to force project to be recompiled? I have looked into command [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build), but haven't found any related parameters.

Comment: Do a `dotnet clean` before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either switch the incremental compilation off by specifying the --no-incremental option (by default the incremental compilation is on which means that compiler will compile the code if it detects any changes in methods, etc) or clean up the output directory.